# Confusing in phpmysql concatenation

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, mysql-error-1064

I have the script like:

```
$sLimit = "";
        if ( isset( $_POST['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_POST['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
        {
                $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
                        mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['iDisplayLength'] );
        }


if ( isset( $_POST['iSortCol_0'] ) )
        {
                $sOrder = "ORDER BY ";
                for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_POST['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
                {
                        if ( $_POST[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_POST['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
                        {
                                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_POST['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                                        ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
                        }
                }

                $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
                if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
                {
                        $sOrder = "";
                }
      }


$sGroupBy = " GROUP BY A.Range_sampling, A.Lot_no ";
                $sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date, A.Line, A.Model, 
                                  A.Lot_no,A.Range_sampling,COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Error,B.name AS PIC
                           FROM inspection_report A
                           LEFT JOIN Employee B
                           ON A.NIK=B.NIK
                           WHERE CHAR_LENGTH( A.Range_sampling ) < 17
                           AND MONTH(A.Inspection_datetime)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)" .$sGroupBy.$sOrder.$sLimit; //error
        $rResult = mysql_query($sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );
```

for this script I got error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 10' at line 7
```

---

after add space show:

```
Error message is :: "Error occuered during query execution: (<small></small>): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc LIMIT 0, 10' at line 8";
```

---

The full query:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date, A.Line, A.Model, A.Lot_no,A.Range_sampling,COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Error,B.name AS PIC FROM inspection_report A LEFT JOIN Employee B ON A.NIK=B.NIK WHERE CHAR_LENGTH( A.Range_sampling ) < 17 AND MONTH(A.Inspection_datetime)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) GROUP BY A.Range_sampling, A.Lot_no ORDER BY desc LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: Give us **plain-text sql** without any php variables at all.

Comment: Can you echo what the full query becomes?

Comment: I'm going to say you are missing a space after LIMIT. I find that the error is usually directly before the string given in the error message. edit -- oops

Comment: doing ....=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) ".$sGroupBy.' '.$sOrder.' '.$sLimit; may fix your issue

Comment: where are you setting $sql? in your error handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put some spaces at the beginning and end of strings like " ORDER BY " and " LIMIT ".

Also, show us the final value of the erroneous sQuery variable.

Now you don't have a field in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

Between BY and desc should be the field name by which you are sorting

Comment: What do you mean of the final value of the erroneous sQuery variable?

Comment: after add space show:`Error message is :: "Error occuered during query execution: (<small></small>): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc LIMIT 0, 10' at line 8";`

Comment: do a `print($sQuery);` just after the assign, and before `$rResult = mysql_query($sQuery) ..` and show us the result of that print, so we can see how the string was built

Comment: I got:`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date, A.Line, A.Model, 
                                  A.Lot_no,A.Range_sampling,COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Error,B.name AS PIC
                           FROM inspection_report A
               LEFT JOIN Employee B
               ON A.NIK=B.NIK
                           WHERE CHAR_LENGTH( A.Range_sampling ) < 17
               AND MONTH(A.Inspection_datetime)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) GROUP BY A.Range_sampling, A.Lot_no  ORDER BY 
                    desc LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: ORDER BY "something" desc LIMIT